# Cannot access input controls page 2 onwards

Tags: javascript, footable

I have a dynamically created table with a number of columns, including a input text control.
I read records from the DB and populate this input field accordingly.
It gets populated correctly on the first page, but not for the other pages.
I am using Footable v3

I tried a bunch of things.
The script seems to go through all the records correctly, but the output is not visible page 2 onwards.

```js
function populateNotes(tableId) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var allRows = FooTable.get(table).rows.all;
    var rowItem, rw;
    var notesTD, jNo;

    // This loop goes through all records correctly
    for (rw in allRows) {
        rowItem = allRows[rw];
        var jNo = rowItem.$el.find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
        console.log("populateNotes: Row: ", jNo);

        var notesTD = rowItem.$el.find("td:nth-child(12)").find('#kpi-notes');
        if (notesTD.length !== 0) {
            notesTD.val('' + getKpiNotes(jNo));
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see the input field 'notesTD' containing the correct value, but this happens only on the first page.
Next page onwards, it is empty.
Appreciate any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the footable events, I use to do this to manage modification of content or style. It also take less time because you only iterate in the 10 or 15 lines of the pages
For example you can use the afterpaging

```
 "after.ft.paging": function (e, ft) {      
            var colarray = ft.columns.array;  //array is just the records shown on the page
........
```